# Javascript implementation of emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs, elisp

What implementations (emulations, clones) of emacs are there that are written in javascript? How are their stability, functionality, and compatibility with the original (GNU emacs)?

**Edit**
I want to embed a text editor in a web application with emacs functionalities. The two answers I have gotten suggest Ymacs and Ace. What are their characteristics? How do they compare?

Comment: Why is this not constructive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably looking for Ace. It's the successor of Bespin/Skywriter. See

http://ace.ajax.org/

or for the code

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace

It is also used by ShareJS, an awesome Google-wave-like tool for collaborative editing. See http://sharejs.org/ and especially the demo here:

http://sharejs.org/code.html

Comment: I didn't know this one. It looks like it's maintained, so it's a good news. The one I had in mind is Ymacs, which was reminded to be by Ivan. I am wondering which one to use. Do you have any idea which is good?

Answer (score 8):

You might be thinking of [Ymacs](http://www.ymacs.org/).  It's written in javascript and I don't feel like porting over my extensive customizations so I have only used the demo a little.  That and I don't have much use for a web text editor.  As far as I can see there is no effort made to make it compatible with Emacs, rather only to be "emacs-like".

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the one that I was thinking. It looks nice. How do you think about it, compared to the Ace, suggested by Willem?

Comment: I haven't used either very much, but Ace looks more popular.  What characteristics do you want?  Easy to install?  Can run elisp?  The ability to read email?

Comment: I want it to have as much customizability and the ability to run elisp libraries. Maybe Ace might be well maintained.

Comment: They both look very customizable and I don't think either can run elisp.  For that you might consider https://github.com/samsonjs/elisp.js which AFAICT isn't finished.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. That looks interesting too.